# How I connect two Routers, one that is wireless only (no Ethernet) on the MIFI side

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

While there seems to be several posts on connecting two wireless routers they all show the solution of having an ethernet connection between the two routers.  In my situation, the Internet facing Router is a MIFI 4GLTE device with no Eithernet ports.  I connect to it via Wireless wifi connection.  The second Router will have Ethernet ports and wireless network.  How do I "Bridge" these two Routers together without a cable between them?

TIA

Comment: Could you provide more details. What model and make is your second router? It is likely that you can't do meshing unless your device supports it.

Comment: I have a NEtGear DGND-3300 but it does not have a bridge option in the setup for the WAN port.  Atleast not to connect to a different brand....

Comment: From what I can tell, I will n eed something that supports DD-WRT ...

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that was following this thread,  the Linksys RE6500 was the solution, it is router independent and it uses wireless as it's upstream connection. Works like a charm.